# Viewing console output when web application is running on Amazon Web Services

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, console

I know that this is a very simple question, but Im new to Amazon Web Services and I need all the help that I can get. When I run my web application locally I can debug by inserting print statements within the code to see if the statement is executed or not (I just look at the console output). Now, I am getting errors in the code when I upload the application to AWS. I do not get these errors when I run the application locally, so I need to debug. Is there a way to see the output of print statements when the application is running on an amazon instance? I can ssh into the instance from my local computer. Is it possible to use the same debugging technique when the code is running remotely? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Everything you see in console should automatically be logged in `catalina.out` file. The file should be located under : `$CATALINA_HOME/logs/`. You will  probably notice multiple files like: `catalina.yyyy-mm-dd.log`. That's  because Tomcat uses [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) with a DailyRollingFileAppender.

From [Tomcat official website](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html):

> When running Tomcat on unixes, the console output is usually redirected to the file named **catalina.out**. The name is configurable using an environment variable. (See the startup scripts). Whatever is written to System.err/out will be caught into that file. That may include: 
>   Uncaught exceptions printed by java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(..)
>   Thread dumps, if you requested them via a system signal
>
> When running as a service on Windows, the console output is also
>   caught and redirected, but the file names are different.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browser you are using you can hit f12 for developer tools and then click on the console tab.

Comment: I opened the console but I didn't get any output.